# Select non-overlapping submatrices by index in a data.frame

Tags: r, matrix

lets say i have a big matrix of length 144.

```
 x <- matrix(1:144, 12, 12)
```

I want to sample 50% of the cells (i.e. 72) but do so in unique submatrices of 2*2. So a total of 18 2*2 matrices.

The indices for each element in the matrices are in a vector such as

```
indices <- 1:144
```

I know how to select groups of 4 cells from indices but my selection picks sub matrices of 1*4 i.e.

```
groups <- rep(1:36, each = 4)
rando_groups <- sample(unique(groups), 18)
df <- data.frame(indices = indices, groups = groups)
sub_mats <- df$indices[df$groups %in% rando_groups]
# 18 sub matrices size of 1*4
```

How can I work out the correct indices to select for 2*2 submatrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice.index` to get *non-overlapping submatrices of 2*2*.

```
x <- matrix(1:144, 12, 12)
nbyn <- 2
groups <- (slice.index(x, 1) - 1) %/% nbyn * nrow(x) / nbyn + (slice.index(x, 2) + nbyn - 1) %/% nbyn
rando_groups <- sample(unique(c(groups)), 18)

which(groups %in% rando_groups)  #Gives you the indices
x[groups %in% rando_groups]      #Gives you the values
groups[groups %in% rando_groups] #Gives you the group
groups %in% rando_groups         #Gives you a matrix of the selected regions
```

Comment: thank you, would you be able to hint at how the line that produces groups would be generalised to submatrices of N*N?

Comment: @user1320502 added `nbyn` but you have to choose it so that it fits in your matrix.